# For which topologies is the pointwise coproduct already a sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topologies

In general, the coproduct of two sheaves is not the coproduct of their underlying presheaves. However, for some topologies, these notions do coincide (e.g. the chaotic topology).

Can anyone point me to further examples of (Grothendieck) topologies for which finite coproducts can be formed pointwise without sheafification? Or is the chaotic topology the only example?